# Transaction being promoted to distributed in Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

We have a problem with transactions that are being promoted to distributed when it shouldn't. We are using Entity Framework 4.1 and TransactionScope in a WCF service:

```
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    public void SetCapLength(Guid orderId, int capLength){}
```

A ObjectContext-instance is created for each service request and only one is used during the entire request.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2.

The promotion to distributed transaction seems very random.

Anyone knows what can cause E.F. to promote our transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TransactionFlowOption` - so if you are lucky and everything is correctly configured the transaction from client flows to your service = distributed transaction. All local transactions on the service side will join the distributed transaction.

Comment: Ah, [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)] may be a bit unintentional. We have a Silverlight client which doesn't create any transactions. I can remove that, but I'm not sure that's the problem?

Comment: No in case of silverlight it will not be a problem. Is it happening on specific operations all the time or randomly? Do you access any other transactional resources?

Comment: It's very random. We have not yet found any pattern and cannot really reproduce it. Sometimes it simply happens. 
No, we don't access other transactional resources. Sometimes the service calls another service, but those are not configured to flow transactions either.